# Adding subview in viewDidLoad has strange bahavior

Tags: ios, swift, view

I am manually creating the `greenView` in the `viewDidload()` method below and add it to `miidLeView` but its coordinates in the resulting screen is wrong? What is the reason for this? Where should add it to `middleView`? Thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!

    var greenRegion : UIView!
    let greenRegionHeight : CGFloat = 100.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



        greenRegion = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: redView.bounds.size.width*1/8,
                                             y: redView.bounds.size.height/2 - greenRegionHeight/2,
                                             width: redView.bounds.size.width*3/4,
                                             height: greenRegionHeight))

        greenRegion.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        redView.addSubview(greenRegion)
    }
```

[image: Here is the screen snapshot]

Comment: What is `middleView` here ?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: middleView is the red one. greenView should be both vertically and horizontally centered inside the red(middle) view.

Comment: What should be your `greenRegion` Width, It should be dynamic as this `redView.bounds.size.width*3/4` ?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `frame` set related code into the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method then everything worked as per expectation.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    greenRegion = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: redView.bounds.size.width*1/8,
                                       y: redView.bounds.size.height/2 - greenRegionHeight/2,
                                       width: redView.bounds.size.width*3/4,
                                       height: greenRegionHeight))

}
```

## Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works when you do it in ViewDidAppear(), too but what is wrong. This behavior came with new xcode update.

Comment: There is nothing related to the XCode update. You're trying to add view before all view positioning set in UI. One more thing it is working ViewDidAppear, It is not working in the viewDidLoad method. If you're going with auto-layout then it is also worked in viewDidLoad method too. Hope it will help you. Another solution is the set frame with some delay. You can consider it OS specific issue not XCode specific issue